# Supervisor event subscription is hanging on READY state

Tags: supervisord

I'm having simple script borrowed from supervisor docs (http://supervisord.org/events.html#event-listeners-and-event-notifications) just to test if the eventlistener is getting any updates from the process it's subscribed to. No matter how state of the process is changed (I'm sending SIGSEGV to program) I'm only able to see "READY" state and none of any other data. 
Question: is listener script supposed to be called manually? 
If not I thought setting the permissions in the following way should be fine to be executable?

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 699 Oct 23 11:33 mylistener.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

to your [eventlistener:x] section and check the logs.